# C program printing newlines

Tags: c, newline

below is my C program for K&R exercise 1-19.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 999

int main (void) {
    printf("Line Reverser.\n");
    printf("This program reverses the input per line.\n");
    middle ();
}
int middle (void) {
    reverse ();
    printf("\n");
    middle ();
}
int reverse (void) {
    int i, c;
    char s[MAXLINE] = {0};
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i <= MAXLINE); ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    };
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    };
    for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it using Code::Blocks, I get the following output if input is asdf.

```
Line Reverser.
This program reverses the input per line.
asdf










fdsa
```

I expected the output to be just fdsa, without the 10 newlines.
I don't understand why there are 10 newlines that are being printed. What am I missing?

Edit: I know this can be done way more efficiently, but this was my first attempt and I'm taking it as a learning experience as to why the newlines are being printed.

Comment: When I run your program, I get infinite garbage. Your `true()` function (not the best name BTW) calls itself recursively and unconditionally. It never stops calling itself, so it will keep printing forever.

Comment: I get three warnings when I compile your code. Fix those warnings.

Comment: Some minor points: `main()` should be `int main(void)`. You don't want a semicolon after the `}` at the end of a function body. I'm not at all sure what the point of your `true` function is, even apart from the fact that it's a recursive infinite loop.

Comment: OK, thanks. But so far as I understand, true() should call reverse() before printing '\n' which should wait for input because of (c = getchar()), no?

Comment: `char s[MAXLINE] = {0};` is too small for the rest of code..

Comment: This is not a valid C program. You call functions before they are declared. Get a more recent book, K&R is outdated since almost 20 years now. Compiler warnings are not to be ignored. Fixe them before asking.

Comment: `s` is an uninitialized array of MAXLINE characters.  If you give 5 characters of input, your program puts data in 6 of the values of the array.  Then it checks the content of all of the entries starting at the end.  What do you expect is in `s[MAXLINE-2]`?

Comment: `i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') ` - that alone should tell you something is wrong in a world of zero-based indexing on an array defined to be `MAXLINE` length. `s[i]` is out of range.

Comment: the lines in your `reverse` function after the line `return 0;` will never get executed since the control has return to main as a result of the return.

Comment: Don't change the code to implement advice you get. This is a Q/A-site. Changing the code may render answers wrong. I have rolled back your post.

Comment: If you have a new question, then post a new question. If you want *working* code reviewed, post it at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, thank you. I will do that.

Comment: regarding: `for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);`  This is where all those blank lines are being output.   Remember that the array `s[]` will only have 6 characters (from asdf\nNul) in it, all other array positions will have 'junk'  so the `reverse()` function needs to start at the character before the '\n' and work to the left,  Not start 1 past the end of the array 's[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct.  At the end of reading the input, the variable `i` has saved the length of the input string, so just use that as the point to start reversing. You likely don't need to save the carriage return at the end of `s` since you don't want it to be at the beginning of the output.  Note also that you need to declare `reverse` before you call it from main.  So you can put the function declaration above main and leave the definition below, or move the entire function definition above main.  So, something like this is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 999

int reverse (void);

int main (void) {
    printf("Line Reverser.\n");
    printf("This program reverses the input per line.\n");
    reverse ();
}

int reverse (void) {
    int i, j, c;
    char s[MAXLINE] = {0};
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i <= MAXLINE); ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    for (j = i; (s[j] != '0') && j >= 0; --j) {
        printf("%c", s[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, when I compile you're program, I get ' fdsa'. I was expecting 'fdsa'. Should I not get 'fdsa'?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your answer. I have fixed the problem now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your program, I get a single newline.

```
$ ./test
Line Reverser.
This program reverses the input per line.
foo

oof$
```

There's a bunch of issues. First, the final `prinf("\n")` never runs because it's immediately after a `return`. Thus the reversed line has no newline on it.

```
for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%c", s[i]);
};
return 0;
printf("\n"); // never runs
```

Second, the code explicitly puts the trailing newline back onto the `s`. This is why there's an extra newline between the input and its reversal.

```
if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = (char)c;
    ++i;
};
```

We can see this with a simple debugging `printf("s = '%s'\n", s);`.

```
$ ./test
Line Reverser.
This program reverses the input per line.
foo
s = 'foo
'

oof$
```

The simple fix is to not put the final newline one, and print the newline before the return.

```
int reverse (void) {
    int i, c;
    char s[MAXLINE] = {0};
    for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i <= MAXLINE); ++i) {
        s[i] = (char)c;
    };
    for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    };
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

$ ./test
Line Reverser.
This program reverses the input per line.
foo
oof
$
```

There's another bug, though it's not the cause of the problem. `(s[i] != '0')` is checking to see if `s[i]` is the character `0` not the number 0. With your test data, it effectively does nothing.

```
for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%d: %c\n", i, s[i]);
}
```

This loop only works because `s` is initialized to be all null bytes. Every character is printed, but they're all null. We can see this by printing `i` as well.

```
for (i = MAXLINE; (s[i] != '0') && i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%d: %c\n", i, s[i]);
}

$ ./test
Line Reverser.
This program reverses the input per line.
foo
999: 
998: 
...
4: 
3: 
2: o
1: o
0: f
```

---

This can be made simpler and more efficient by reading from the end of the line, not the end of the buffer. We can remember how large the string is while we read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(void) {
    // Use BUFSIZ from stdio
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    // Read a line, but not the newline.
    // buf_idx remembers where the end of the line is.
    size_t buf_idx;
    int c;
    for(
        buf_idx = 0;
        ((c = getchar()) && (c != EOF) && (c != '\n') );
        buf_idx++
    ) {
        buf[buf_idx] = (char)c;
    }

    // A for loop always executes all its statements, even when the
    // condition fails, so we need to back up one.
    // Stick a null on the end of buf. It's not necessary, but just
    // in case we want to print it for debugging.
    buf[buf_idx--] = '\0';


    // Print the characters from the end to the start.
    for( int i = (int)buf_idx; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }

    // Print a trailing newline.
    printf("\n");
}
```

`BUFSIZ` is a good size for a read buffer decided by the operating system. It's provided by [stdio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#Constants).

It's not necessary to spend the runtime initializing `buf` because we only ever read from it what we write. Though it's probably a good idea to stick a null on the end anyway.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I run the program with Code::Blocks, I get an error "undefined reference to WinMain@16." What is the cause of this error?

Comment: @AncientBehemoth It's not a complete program so you'd have to think a bit about it. Did you remember to write a `main` routine which calls `reverse`?

Comment: Yes I did. Apparently the error disappeared after I rebooted the system. Thank you.